# Mimes Validation not working correctly in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

My webpage contains a file for upload, and I want the file uploaded to only be either pdf, doc or docx.

My form tag also has enctype="multipart/form-data"

My html looks like:

```
<div id="cv_upload" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input type="file" name='cv'>
    </div>
</div>
```

The $rules array associated with this is as follows:

```
'cv' => 'mimes:application/pdf,application/doc,application/docx|required'
```

And finally my messages looks like:

```
'cv.required' => 'A selection for C.V. is required before proceeding.',
'cv.mimes' => 'CV must be of the following file type: pdf, doc or docx.'
```

The only problem with this is, even after I upload a pdf or doc, the message I receive is the one for required. I have no idea why this isn't working as expected. I also tried removing the 'application/' but that yields no success either. Please help.

Answer (score 26):

Make sure your form has an attribute **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

Also, if you use **mimes** validation the format must be ***'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'***
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-mimes

You can read about the enctype attribute here : [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: Adding the form attribute solved my problem, worth trying it out!

Answer (score 0):

In form try put `files="true"`.

In validator try put the validations eg `required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-mimes

Edit: When you use `mimes:application/doc`, actually is **`mimetypes:application/doc`**

Comment: no luck :/ I put both but it still isn't able to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the similar issue , everything was correct after hiting following cmds issue got resolved
`php artisan cache:clear  , php artisan config:clear , php artisan route:clear`

Comment: With one command to cover all of that `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 0):

Use validation as below if you are facing any issue with .docx extension files

```
'cv' => 'mimetypes:application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/octet-stream,application/pdf'
```

This will help to validate doc, Docx, and pdf files.

To show proper error message use the below code:

```
public function messages ()
{
    return [
        'cv.mimetypes' => 'The cv file must be a file of type: pdf, doc, docx.'
    ];
}
```

Reference: [Laravel 7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-mimetypes)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets the same problem, you have to use the file exstension, but not the mime type like so:

```
'file' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf,doc,docx'
```

The full list of the extensions can be found: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types